# String matching to download certain files

Tags: r, regex

I wish to download the quarterly "NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk" files for 2018 and 2019 and all years going forward from the cms.gov [website](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Part-B-Drugs/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/2018ASPFiles.html).

Looking at the names of the files they appear to change slightly for each quarter but have the same overall structure:

year-mon/mon-year-*-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip

Here are the historical file names I wish to download:

- 2018-January-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- 2018-April-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- 2018-July-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- 2018-Oct-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- January-2019-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- April-2019-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip
- 2019-July-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip

I've figured out how to download some of these files individually and unzip them and read the XLS files that are contained within but I was hoping for a more elegant or scalable way to do this into the future.

Currently my code looks as follows:

```
#DEFINE THE MONTHS OF THE FILES WE WANT TO RETRIEVE
months <- c("January", "April", "July", "Oct")

#FIND THE URLS OF THE FILES WE NEED
urls <- sprintf("https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Part-B-Drugs/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/Downloads/%s-2019-ASP-NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip", months)

#DOWNLOAD FILES IF THEY DO NOT EXIST (https://nicercode.github.io/guides/repeating-things/)
download.maybe <- function(urls, refetch=FALSE, path = ".") {
  dest <- file.path(path, basename(urls))
  if (refetch || !file.exists(dest))
    download.file(urls, dest)
  dest
}

path <- "data"
dir.create(path, showWarnings = FALSE)
files <- sapply(urls, download.maybe, path=path)
```

Rather than passing the months to sprintf can I pass a wildcard such as if it contains (2018 or 2019) AND (Jan*, Ap*, Jul*, Oct*) then download the files?

Comment: I think a pattern like this would get what you're looking for: `((Jan|Jul|Apr|Oct).*?-\\d{4}|\\d{4}-(Jan|Jul|Apr|Oct).*?).+HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip`... That said, unless I'm missing something, it looks like, of the downloadable files on the linked page, you just want the ones containing `HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip`, no? In which case, that's the only pattern you'd really need to check for.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure whether it's the pattern-matching that you're having trouble with, or the 'getting the urls from the webpage' component.

Comment: @Hayden Y. Thanks for the reply, yes I am just looking for the HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip files but just from 2018 going forward. How can I Incorporate this into the URL piece?

Comment: Perhaps read the source page and apply an XPath similar to `//a/@href[contains(., 'NDC-HCPCS-Crosswalk.zip')]`

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to scrape the page you want. We can get all the `href` attribute on the page, select only the ones which end with `"zip"` and then use `download.file` to download them all.

```
url <- "https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Part-B-Drugs/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/2018ASPFiles.html"
library(rvest)


all_urls <- url %>%
             read_html() %>%
             html_nodes("a") %>%
             html_attr("href") %>%
             grep("HCPCS-Crosswalk\\.zip$", ., value = TRUE)
             paste0("https://www.cms.gov", .)


lapply(all_urls, function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
```

Comment: Note that there are other zip files on the page, so I'd change `grep("\\.zip$", ., value = TRUE)` to `grep("HCPCS-Crosswalk\\.zip", ., value = TRUE)`